# How to add panels inside nav-content in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a nav-tabs on the left side of tab-contents which I'm able to accomplish successfully, but as soon as I add a panel inside of the tab-contents div, the nav-tabs float inside of the panel header.

[Bootply DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/WYBcKAaA4s)

What do I need to do have the tabs to float to the left of the tab-contents div?

Comment: try adding margin-left to div class tab-content http://www.bootply.com/1Qo5Vw5Kde

Comment: That solves my problem! :)

Comment: ... but will not accommodate variation in tab width. http://www.bootply.com/TMEyrUtMSZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 .tab-content {display: inline-block;}
```

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/HM9bVDlo74)**

This solution doesn't depend on fragile fixed dimensions.

**[Long tab demo](http://www.bootply.com/qohhNm0krt)**